# Convert a numeric column with number eg.(-1222222) to two float column with two decimal places eg (-12222.22)

Tags: sql-server, cast, floating-point

I know there are different variations of this question asked.
But what I am trying to do is that, there is a table with a numeric column (12,0)
that has data looking like

```
Units
-----
-1222222
0
-19
21123021
```

What they really mean is this

```
Units
-----
-12222.22
0.00
-0.19
211230.21
```

With two decimal places in the last digits of each number.

I am struggling to convert these numbers to a two decimal place float column(Units)

Comment: Try units/100.00

Comment: @JoeDBA_HAHAHA Now i feel dumb...I was doing units/100 and kept getting an integer number. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
with data as 
(
select -1222222 as foo 
union
select 0
union 
select -19
union 
select 21123021
)
select cast(cast(foo as decimal)/100 as decimal(10,2))
from data;
```

You can also use `format(foo,'N2')` and a million other ways.